# SQL GETDATE() Inserting 01/01/001 12:00:00 AM to database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, localdb

In my service-based SQL database one of my table has a column 'feedbackdate' with default value `GETDATE()`. I am using entity framework to insert data to the table and not mentioning the said column in the insert statement but `GETDATE()` function is inserting `01/01/001 12:00:00 AM` . I also tried `current_timestamp` and `sysdatetime()` and `sysdatetime().NOW()` as Default-Value but result is same.

I also changed the DataType of column from `date` to `datetime2(0)` but no luck.

Column definition in table

```
[feedBackDate]      DATETIME2 (0)  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) NOT NULL,
```

Note: I am using Database-First Model and in EntityDataModel the mapped column's `Default Value` is `NONE`

Comment: Have you examined the generated `insert` sql?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I don't recognize the DATETIME2 data type.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL (LocalDb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. The problem is with the Mapped Column in .edmx file. I've changed the `StorGenereatePattern` from `None` to `Computed` of the mapped column and bingo.